# How do I cut off one half of a PDF page?

Tags: itext

I want to print a DHL label using a label printer.

The DHL label consists of 2 parts: The left half of the image is just info that I can keep to myself. The right part of the PDF is what should actually be printed.

I would therefore like to cut away the left part of the PDF.
I do not want to make it blank, but I really I want to cut if off.

How could I do this?

[image]

Comment: Consider setting the crop box of the page to encompass only the desired right part of the current page.

Comment: @mkl Would you mind trying to give an answer? I am absolutely not familiar with iTextSharp. I find it so extremely error prone with all the quirks and catches like GetInstance() and such...

Comment: Can you share an example DHL parcel label PDF? Otherwise I can only give you some generic source for changing the extend of the page.

Comment: @mkl Yes, I have uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MPVn8P-S0olyR1MoT1T5fNLgxe6epQiS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok. Looking at your screenshot I assume you want to keep the top half, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially want to cut away one half of the PDF page; looking at you screenshot most likely the lower half.

Using iTextSharp 5.5.13.3 you can do that like this:

```csharp
var testFile = @"new pdf1.pdf";
var resultFile = @"new pdf1-Cut.pdf";

using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(testFile))
using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, File.Create(resultFile)))
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        Rectangle cropBox = pdfReader.GetCropBox(i);
        PdfArray newCropBox = new PdfArray(new float[] {
                cropBox.Left, (cropBox.Bottom + cropBox.Top) / 2,
                cropBox.Right, cropBox.Top });

        PdfDictionary pageDictionary = pdfReader.GetPageN(i);
        pageDictionary.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, newCropBox);
        pageDictionary.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, newCropBox);
    }
}
```

*([CutPages](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/csharp/stamp/CutPages.cs#L19) test `CutInHalfForTmighty`)*

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Screenshot original] | [image: Screenshot cut] |